# MailChimp.Net User is not subscribed

Tags: asp.net, .net, mailchimp

I'm trying to call MailChimp Subscribe with MailChimp.Net NuGet package to add user to list in MailChimp.

The request is performed with success as far as I can see from MailChimp dashboard but the user is not subscribed in the list.

Did anyone faced such issue?

```
var myMergeVars = new MergeVar();
            myMergeVars.Add("FNAME", "Testy");
            myMergeVars.Add("LNAME", "Testerson");

            var mc = new MailChimpManager("MYKEY");

            //  Create the email parameter
            var email = new EmailParameter()
            {
                Email = "test.spektor@gmail.com"
            };

            EmailParameter results = mc.Subscribe("LISTID", email);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The request should be made with `doubleOptIn: false` option, otherwise user will receive an email with confirmation on his email box.

```
var result = mc.Subscribe(listId, emailParameter, myMergeVars, doubleOptIn: false, updateExisting: true);
```

Comment: hey Jack how did you configure options? can you share some sample codes? I have no idea how to disable doubleOptIn

Comment: Hi Lion. 

var result = mc.Subscribe(listId, emailParameter, myMergeVars, doubleOptIn: false, updateExisting: true);

This is code snippet from the .NET wrapper for the MailChimp